# Validate if English word is valid as in found in dictionary Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, wordnet

Developing a Dart Flutter app. I need to validate if an English word that the user inputted is in the dictionary or not.
Is there a package or API interface to Wordnet or similar dictionary?
Is it possible to get from the dictionary of word is verb, adjective or noun?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to find an API, if you find one, then you will have to communicate with it by using the 'http' package of Flutter and by creating your implementation.

**If no API is available** and *I think it is the case* (I'm not 100% sure), then you have two options.

The first one is to create a scraper for the dictionaries or the website, you can use the WordNet web interface(http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) and use the `web_scraper` plugin to try to access and retrieve the data (make sure you have the rights to do so).

The second option (for me the best), is to create your own API knowing that WordNet offers to download their database file under license.(https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download)
You can use a web framework(Express.Js https://expressjs.com/fr/ is quite simple) depending on the language you use to create your api rest using the WordNet database file or by creating a database with this file.
Clearly, it's complicated but not impossible, the last option is the most complex and the first one is rather unstable...

I specify that this answer is only my opinion and maybe there is another solution, if yes I let then other person answer.